# How can i convert an object to the structure { [param: string]: string | string[] }?

Tags: typescript

Hi I have a class in typescript named Flight.

```
export interface Flight {
  id: string;
  campaign: Campaign;
  name: string;
  contactList: ContactList;
  createdBy: User;
  endDate: string;
  impressionLimit: number;
  inventory: FlightInventory;
  location: Location;
  profile: Profile;
  recipientGatheringList: RecipientGathering;
  startDate: string;
  status: FlightStatus;
  validityPeriod: number;
  roamingSubscribers: boolean;
  createdOn: string;
  lastUpdated: string;
  impressionLimitPerSubscriber: number;
  urgency: FlightTagOnUrgencyCode;
  coolingOffPeriod: number;
  timeframe: Timeframe;
  fallbackToSMS: boolean;
  tagOnTypes: TagOn[];
  tagOnTargetRecipients: TagOnTargetRecipient[];
}
```

Also in one of the method i have an instance of Flight as a method parameter. I would like to convert the flight object to a type of { [param: string]: string | string[] } . how can i achieve that?

```
  getTagonMessagePrefix(flight: Flight) {


    const isTagOn = flight.inventory.code === FlightInventoryCode.TAG_ON;
    let tagonMessagePrefix;
    if(isTagOn){
      tagonMessagePrefix = this.http.get<TagOnMessagePrefix>(`${this.config.api}/flights/${flight.id}/tagon/messageprefix`);
    }  else {
      tagonMessagePrefix = Observable.of({});
    }
    return tagonMessagePrefix;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I did not understasnd what do you mean by convert but if you need to just "change" the types of properties you can create generic interface that will convert them

```
interface MakeAryOrString<T> {
    [P in keyof T]: string | string[]
}
```

This will create new type based on `Flight` that will have all properties `string | string[]`.

```
let changedFLight: MakeAryOrString<Flight> = ...;
```